# Not getting DbgPrintEx prints on windows debugger running on host (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, driver

My driver is deployed successfully on windows 10 target PC. But still i am not getting debug prints on windows debugger (WinDbgX64) session on my HOST PC.

I have also set **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter** key's "**DEFAULT**" *DWORD* to value **8**. So that my **DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL** will be able to send data to kernel buffer.

The installing and configuration of components for driver deployment and testing via visual studio is commenced successfully. Hence it has created a WDKRemoteUser account on my target machine to deploy the drivers.

My Host Environment:- Windows 10 (Build 10130) X64 and Visual studio 2015 RC with all required component installed.

My Target Environment:- Windows 10 (Build 10130) X64 and debugging & testing components installed.

My debug print statement inside driver entry routine is as follows.

DbgPrintEx(**DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID**, **DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL**, "KMDFHelloWorldDriver: DriverEntry\n");

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be setting IHVDRIVER's value to 8 instead of DEFAULT's value, if you are using DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID in the DbgPrintEx?